# How to get Total number of Records for particular recordtype using Netsuite API?

Tags: php, netsuite

Any idea how to get total number of records for particular record type using
netsuite api.

recordtype would be a contact,customer,lead,prospect,vendor,othername,partner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a search and ask for a column "internalid" with summary type of COUNT. This is how it would look in Suitescript.

```
var columns = [];
var filters= [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid', null, 'COUNT'));
var results = nlapiSearchRecord('contact', null, filters, columns);
```

You could create this search ad-hoc in your PHP script or you could pre-create a saved search and load it in PHP and retrieve the results.

This example is for the record type of contact. Just do the same thing for the other record types.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getCounts(typevalue) {
    console.log("value" + typevalue);
    var countSearch = {};
    var type = typevalue;
    var columns = [ {
        name : 'internalid',
        summary : 'COUNT'
    } ];
    var filters = [];
    countSearch.type = type;
    countSearch.columns = columns;
    countSearch.filters = filters;
    var mySearchObj = search.create(countSearch);
    var value;
    var resultset = mySearchObj.run();
    var results = resultset.getRange(0, 100);
    for ( var i in results) {
        var result = results[i];
        value = result.getValue(result.columns[0]);

    }
    return value;
}
```

//Pass the RECORD type  in typevalue parameter of getCounts()function.